# C# multiple writeattributestring to xml not showing in correct order

Tags: c#, xml

```
            xtw.WriteStartElement("cXML");                               
            xtw.WriteAttributeString("payloadID", payloadidstr);
            xtw.WriteAttributeString("timestamp", utctime());
            xtw.WriteAttributeString("version", "1.2.024");
```

above code working fine to generate xml attribute. if open xml file in notepad shows the following string which is correct.

cXML payloadID="1392408819113-4172669982087053277@123.456.789.10" timestamp="2014-02-14T12:13:39-08:00" version="1.2.024"

but when open xml file in any browser the attribute order is changed showing like this.

cXML version="1.2.024" timestamp="2015-01-15T16:54:48-08:00" payloadID="150120150454480293-832257153@123.456.789.10"

Can someone let me know why browser not showing in correct order or how to shows multiple string under one element.

Comment: perhaps the browser is doing some schema validation and reporting the attributes back in the order they are expected.

Comment: Per the spec: `the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant` http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags

Answer (score 2):

XML does not define ordering of attributes, so there is no "correct" order - compliant reader/writers are free to order the way they pleased.

Per the spec  [section 3.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags):

> the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant

Comment: Thanks @Andreas for finding the spec link

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I am new in XML development. I tried to learn spec as you mention but do not understand. Can you provide the some solution. Another notice when I open the XML file in Free XML editor it shows in correct order but why not in the browser.

Comment: @ShahabKhan I'm not sure what solution you are looking for - order is not defined/important for elements, so everyone is free to show attributes in order they want, including one that matches textual representation of XML. But you as user generally have no control over it.